# Simple Rails 3 Route is Failing - No route matches 

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my config/routes.rb I have:

```
  post "portal_plan_document/update"
```

rake routes confirms this:

```
$ rake routes
portal_plan_document_update POST /portal_plan_document/update(.:format) {:controller=>"portal_plan_document", :action=>"update"}
....
```

In my code I have:

```
<%= form_for @plan_doc, 
    :url => portal_plan_document_update_path, 
    :method => "POST", :remote => true do |f| %>
```

In my log file I see:

```
Started POST "/portal_plan_document/update" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-03-31 18:04:37 -0400

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/portal_plan_document/update"):
```

I am lost as what to do from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I should state I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.0.5. Oh, I have restarted the server (WebBrick w/rails server) after updating routes.rb.

Jeremy

Comment: I did find that if I changed :method => "POST" to :method => "PUT" and change my route keyword "post" to "put" that all works great. Changing them back to "post" causes it all to fail as stated above. So, put works, post fails!?

Comment: I've discovered this same problem on my code today. put works, post fails.

Comment: Most browsers don't really support anything other than GET and POST requests, so Rails fakes PUT and DELETE with hidden fields in POST. See Yen's answer below for the fix.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out! :)
if you have a non-empty object, rails assumes you want to update that object. i.e., use a 'PUT' instead of a 'POST'

to accomplish 'PUTs', rails will put a hidden input in the form, with "_method" = "put". so, it LOOKS like it's a POST, but rails is treating it as a PUT.

if you actually want to just update an object (what it looks like you're doing), a PUT is better, and you should just switch your routes over to PUT.

if (like I was), you're doing something that really requires a POST (i.e., it can't be sent more than once safely), you can write your form_for like this:

```
<%= form_for @plan_doc, 
:url => portal_plan_document_update_path, 
:html=>{:method => "POST"}, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

to confirm, look at the generated HTML source, and make sure the hidden "_method" field is not set to "put"

Answer (score 0):

Try using that instead please :

```
:method => :post
```

If this does not still work, please lose the remote attribute and give it a try. Does it work without it ?

Comment: Neither work. The request is going across as a post method, as confirmed by rails itself, in the log it says "Started POST /portal_plan_document/update".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while upgrading a simple app from Rails 2 to Rails 3.
As you may guess I was updating all "remote_form_for(@item) (..)" helpers to "form_for :item remote => true (..)" syntax.

In my case this code from a items/_new.html.erb partial:

```
<%= form_for :item, :remote => true do |f| %>
<!--FIELDS-->
<% end %>
```

Gave me this error:

> Started **POST** "/items/new" for 127.0.0.1 at Fri Aug 12 18:19:23
>   +0200 2011
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/items/new")

As you can notice the method was a correct "POST", not a "PUT". The problem lied in the routing... I don't know why but when a remote POST method is sent by a partial, Rails routes the POST request to "/items/new" instead of "/items" route. Even if the purpose is to create a new "item" so the POST request should be correctly (and RESTfully) routed to "/items".

This code, with explicit action and controller, solved the problem:

```
<%= form_for :item, :remote => true, :url => { :controller => "items", :action => "create" } do |f| %>
<!--FIELDS-->
<% end %>
```